# Twitter Bootstrap Change table alignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap in my rails app. I am trying to get the table header to display in the same row as the table data. Something similar to this

```
<tr align="left"><th>Due Date:</th><td><%= @invoice.due_date %></td>
</tr>
```

How can I accomplish this in twitter bootstrap?

Comment: So you want the header running vertically instead of horizontally?

Comment: Correct, I want the header vertically and the values also vertically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap doesn't have anything to do with it.

For each `<tr>` in your table, just use `<th>` for the cells you want emphasised.

If you're saying you want the row dividers to become column dividers, that's a bit of custom CSS along the lines of...

```
.table-vertical tr
{
  border: none !important;
}

.table-vertical th
{
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
}
```

... and so on.